# Xamarin Forms: Sharing to WeChat with SharePlugin on iOS

Tags: plugins, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, share, wechat

We've implemented [**SharePlugin**](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin) to our project. 
Everything is great except shares link to WeChat on iOS. It's always shown an oddly thumbnail images.

[image]

My question is how could I set this thumbnail images? Or hide this thumbnail images?

Comment: I am afraid that SharePlugin does not have an interface to set the size and content mode of the image.It defined by WeChat's API.The iamge will appear when you set the url.

Comment: is it possibly to hide it?